# Iteratively join tree branches/nodes that have the same leaf values

Tags: python, tree

Let's say I have a dataframe with features `x..` and outcomes `y`:

```
import pandas as pd

def crossing(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.merge(df1.assign(key=1), df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop(columns='key')

def crossing_many(*args):
    from functools import reduce
    return reduce(crossing, args)

df = crossing_many(
    pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['A', 'B', 'C']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'x2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'x3': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']}),
).assign(y = lambda d: np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(d)))
```

I can plot a tree with `bigtree` package quite simply:

```
from bigtree import dataframe_to_tree
def view_pydot(pdot):
    from IPython.display import Image, display
    plt = Image(pdot.create_png())
    display(plt)

tree = (
    df
    .assign(y=lambda d: d['y'].astype('str'))
    .assign(root='Everyone')
    .assign(path=lambda d: d[['root'] + features + ['y']].agg('/'.join, axis=1))
    .pipe(dataframe_to_tree, path_col='path')
)

view_pydot(tree_to_dot(tree))
```

I get something like: [image]

Tree is way complex than it could be. I want to iteratively "join" branches/nodes that have the same leave node - on all levels. For example, something like that:

[image]

Basically I want to create as simple tree as possible so person will be able to use it in the sense, IF x1=A AND x2=X THEN 1 (so come to the decision through the shortest path possible). It would also make sense to remove nodes that cover all possible values for this features (for example `xxx|yyy|zzz`). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using `bigtree`! This feels like an algorithm question where you need to do some tree manipulation here. A solution is to **combine sibling nodes in a tree if they have the same descendants**.

For example, `X/xxx` with descendant `0` (`X/xxx/0`) and its sibling `X/zzz` with descendant `0` (`X/zzz/0`) can be combined to `X/xxx|zzz` with descendant `0`.

The code snippet below is separated into the setup and the solution.

```py
# Set up
from bigtree import list_to_tree, tree_to_dot

root = list_to_tree([
    "Everyone/A/X/xxx/0",
    "Everyone/A/X/yyy/1",
    "Everyone/A/X/zzz/0",
    "Everyone/A/Y/xxx/1",
    "Everyone/A/Y/yyy/0",
    "Everyone/A/Y/zzz/1",
    "Everyone/A/Z/xxx/0",
    "Everyone/A/Z/yyy/1",
    "Everyone/A/Z/zzz/0",
    "Everyone/B/X/xxx/1",
    "Everyone/B/X/yyy/0",
    "Everyone/B/X/zzz/0",
    "Everyone/B/Y/xxx/1",
    "Everyone/B/Y/yyy/0",
    "Everyone/B/Y/zzz/0",
    "Everyone/B/Z/xxx/0",
    "Everyone/B/Z/yyy/1",
    "Everyone/B/Z/zzz/1",
    "Everyone/C/X/xxx/1",
    "Everyone/C/X/yyy/0",
    "Everyone/C/X/zzz/0",
    "Everyone/C/Y/xxx/0",
    "Everyone/C/Y/yyy/1",
    "Everyone/C/Y/zzz/0",
    "Everyone/C/Z/xxx/0",
    "Everyone/C/Z/yyy/1",
    "Everyone/C/Z/zzz/1",
])
tree_to_dot(root).write_png("before.png")
```

Before:
[image: Before]

```py
# Solution
from bigtree import Node, postorder_iter, tree_to_dot
from typing import List

def get_descendant_paths(_node: Node) -> List[str]:
    return sorted([descendant.path_name.removeprefix(_node.path_name) for descendant in _node.descendants])

# Iterate through the tree in the bottom-up fashion
for node in postorder_iter(root):
    for node_sib in node.siblings:
        # If nodes have the same descendants
        if get_descendant_paths(node) == get_descendant_paths(node_sib):
            node.name = f"{node.name}|{node_sib.name}"
            node_sib.parent = None

tree_to_dot(root).write_png("after.png")
```

After:
[image: After]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `bigtree` :)

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, thanks a lot. Would you also be able to help me with changing the shape of the leaves and their color based on their value (either 0 or 1)? I can ask another question for that.

Comment: Hi, no problem feel free to raise it as an issue here https://github.com/kayjan/bigtree/issues and I can address it there :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve your problem using [littletree](https://github.com/lverweijen/littletree) (I'm the author).
The code might not be the most efficient way to solve this, but it works.

```py
# df was created using code by OP

import itertools
from littletree import Node

# Convert df to tree
tree = Node.from_rows(df, path_name=None)
tree.identifier = "Everyone"
tree.to_image('before.png')


def simplify_tree(tree):
    """Simplify it iteratively."""
    tree = tree.copy()
    for node in tree.iter_tree(order="post"):
        children = list(node.children)
        for s1, s2 in itertools.combinations(children, 2):
            if not s1.compare(s2):
                s1.identifier += "|" + s2.identifier
                s2.detach()
    return tree


new_tree = simplify_tree(tree)
new_tree.to_image('after.png')
```

Before:
[image: Tree before simplification]

After:
[image: Tree after simplification]

Since the problem has to do with simplifying boolean expressions, you may also want to look into [Karnaugh mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).